# Angular 4 проверка ползовотеля

Tags: angular2, angular-routing, angular4

Делаю проверку на пользователя который лежит на localstorage

```
import {AuthService} from "./auth.service";
import {UsersService} from "./users.service";
import {User} from "../models/user.model";
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {
  private user: User;
  constructor( private userService: UsersService,
                private  authService: AuthService,
                private router: Router ) {}
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
    if (window.localStorage.getItem("user") !== null) {
      this.user = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("user"));





        this.userService.getUserByEmail(this.user.email)
          .subscribe((user: User) => {

            if (user) {
              if (user.password === this.user.password) {
                return true;
              }
              else {
                this.router.navigate(['/login'], {
                  queryParams: {
                    accessDenied: true
                  }
                });
                return false;
              }
            }
            else {
              this.router.navigate(['/login'], {
                queryParams: {
                  accessDenied: true
                }
              });
              return false;
            }
          });

    }
    else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: {
        accessDenied: true
      }
      });
      console.log("false 3");
      return false;
    }
  }
  canActivateChild(childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
    return this.canActivate(childRoute, state);
  }
}
```

userService:

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

import {User} from '../models/user.model';
import {BaseApi} from '../core/base-api';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService extends BaseApi {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    super(http);
  }


  getUserByEmail(email: string): Observable<User> {
    return this.get('users?email=' + email)
      .map((user: User[]) => user[0] ? user [0] : undefined);
  }
  createNewUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
    return this.post('users', user);
  }
}
```

но каким то боком он походу поздно возвращает true . Проблема в том что он не меняет url а остается в http://localhost:4200/

Только изучаю